# Cauchy's theorem- understanding the proof

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

> Let $G$ be a bounded domain with smooth boundary $\partial G$. Then, if $f$ is analytic on $\partial G$ and inside $G$ we have
> \begin{equation}
> \oint_{\partial G}f(z)dz=0
> \end{equation}

The proof is as follows:

Write $f(x+iy)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$. Then the integral we want is:

\begin{align}
\oint_{\partial G}f(z)dz&=\oint_{\partial G}(udx-vdy)+i\oint_{\partial G}(vdx+udy)\\&=-\iint_G\left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)dxdy+\iint_G\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\right)dxdy\\&=0
\end{align}

where we have used the Cauchy-Riemann equations and also Green's theorem.

Question: Why can we decompose $f(x+iy)=(u+iv)dx-(v-iu)dy$? I don't understand this at all

Comment: $u$ is the real part and $v$ the imaginary part of the complex number $f(x+iy)$.

Answer (score 1):

It's not just $f(z)$ but $f(z)dz$: $$f(z)dz = (u+iv)d(x+iy) = (u+iv)(dx+idy)$$ $$=(u+iv)dx +(u+iv)idy=(u+iv)dx +(ui-v)dy$$

Note that it's a little bit informal to work with complex differentials for those just from a rigorous real analysis course, but there is nothing wrong with it.